# Asp.net mvc5 online calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar

I use Sql Server and Asp.net mvc5 .I want to make a page with calendar.The Calendar shows that whether employee come late or in time this information will come from database .I have searched some online calendars but I haven't dealed with it Do you have an idea how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with fullcalendar to achieve this functionality. In this calendar, you can bind json data to the calendar. This is really awesome in terms of UI and events. I also used this to achieve the same functionality.
Go through to https://fullcalendar.io/

If need any help, write here.